# Parse XML Scheme file and retrieve values in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, xsd

I have an XML Scheme file like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns="urn:myNS" 
    targetNamespace="urn:myNS" 
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="some_name">
        <xs:complexType>
             <xs:all>
             ...
```

I need to get the values of `targetNamespace` and `element name` into Strings (in Android).

Is there a parser to do it? Can anybody suggest a way to do it?

Coding examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Android support some  XML parsers used in Java i.e. SAX Parser, DOM Parser and PULL Parser etc. You can use any of them. This [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/) may help you.